# How do I load a specific javascript file or javascript code into an HTML document?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's what I'm trying to do;

I have this HTML code:

```
<div id="background-color-random">
    DIV CONTENT
</div>
```

And this javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var colors = ["#FFA347", "#FF5050", "#FF66FF", "#6699FF", "#00FF99"],
selectedColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)]
header = $("div#background-color-random");

header.css("background-color", selectedColor);
});
```

I want to impliment this on an HTML page. I know that you can load up a *.js file by using the script tags with src="..". But that doesn't seem to work.

The javascript creates a random color and then applies that to the background of a given 'div' in the HTML.

Now, I'm not good with javascript, so please be patient with me and simple answers are needed :)

I need to be able to get the javascript to load when requested from the HTML and then apply itself to the div with id="..".

Comment: Any error in your console ? (f12)
 Are you loading jQuery ?

Comment: you are using JQuery functions without loading it first... suggest you go to http://learn.jquery.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using jQuery, not pure javascript. That's a good thing...

but you also must add the jQuery library in your head tags, like this:

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

You also need to put semi-colons (or commas, as RobM has corrected me, if between var assignments) at the end of each instruction. See line 3 in your code example.

If you want your js/jQuery code in a separate file, you can load the script code like this (again, usually done in the `<head>` tags):

```
<script src="filename.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Or, you can include the js/jQ in the `<head>` tags of your document, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var colors = ["#FFA347", "#FF5050", "#FF66FF", "#6699FF", "#00FF99"],
        selectedColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)],
        header = $("div#background-color-random");

        header.css("background-color", selectedColor);
    });
</script>
```

If including the script as an external file, you leave out the `<script></script>` wrapper from that file.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is it a good thing to use jQuery over plain Javascript?

Comment: Commas are valid in declaring multiple variables, they do not need to use semicolons

Comment: Automatically cross-browser compatible, for one. Plus, many find it much easier to learn and it is about 30% less typing. Many reasons.

Comment: @RobM. Aaii, you're right - I missed that. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: I think an argument could be made that performing a task as simple as this could be done in plain javascript without loading a large library; I don't necessarily disagree with you, but developers lean a little too hard on jQuery and other libraries without enough focus on understanding "plain" javascript.

Comment: I agree with you, but (remembering my own early days) I found jQuery significantly easier to learn than pure js -- and probably much of that was due to the cross-browser compat and less typing. Call me biased I guess. In my case, I learned jQuery first -- and developed a couple dozen sites - while filling in the gaps in my pure js knowledge. Every now and then I think back to the extra typing time I've saved...

Comment: Yes, this has worked. I needed to load the jquery src into the css and then just simply insert the jquery code into script tags

Comment: @user2649843 Good point... I neglected to answer that part of your question. See changes to my answer above.

Comment: Yeah, thats exactly what I did, I needed the jQ to load every time the web page was loaded so I used the script tags with the actual jQ code, rather than reffering to it, to put the code into the HTML document, cheers.

Answer (score 3):

You have a syntax error (missing a comma):

```
selectedColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)]
header = $("div#background-color-random");
```

Should be

```
selectedColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)],
header = $("div#background-color-random");
```